# How to access the underlying value of state with correct type in Typst

Tags: typst

I'm currently building a template with polylux where the user can define one of five color themes.
As the chosen color theme is global state I used the `state` type.
My colors are organized as a map and i want to use the chosen color scheme as a key for it, to get the correct colors.
Howver I'm running into type issues as state stores everything as `any`.

A barebones example would be:

```
#let RedTheme = (light: rgb(255, 0, 0), dark: rgb(128, 0, 0))

#let GreenTheme = (light: rgb(0, 255, 0), dark: rgb(0, 128, 0))

#let AllThemes = (theme1: RedTheme, theme2: GreenTheme)

#let theme = state("theme", "theme1")

// sets up state
#let template(user-theme: "", body) = {
  theme.update(user-theme)

  body
}

#show: template.with(user-theme: "theme2")

// FIXME: this is broken
#let color = AllThemes.at(state("theme").display())
```

Whenever i try to do something like: `AllColors.at(state("scheme").display())` i get an error essentielly telling me content cannot be used as string.

Am I missing some conversion function or is this even the right approach?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Just added one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap the code into a locate so similar to extract the value of state.

```
#let with-theme(body) = {
  locate(loc => {
    let theme-color = AllThemes.at(state("theme").at(loc))
    body(theme-color)
  })
}

#show: template.with(user-theme: "theme2")

#with-theme(theme => {
  rect(width: 12pt, fill: theme.light)
})
```

But this inconvenience only happens when you want to use a state, of which main use case is counters. Otherwise just use a normal variable and you're just fine.

```
// in template:
#let get-theme(name) = AllThemes.at(name)

// In main.typ:
#let theme = get-theme("theme1")
rect(width: 12pt, fill: theme.light)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! this got me started :)

My main reason for using states is that I need the color mostly in the template and not the user's code. So I wanted to just set the users-theme once in the setup function (#template) and then use it throughout the template.
I also want to provide the user with something like ColorA, ColorB which is an interpolated color between light and dark, so depending on the theme.
Is this possible without either always having to pass theme (if it is defined as a variable by the user) or always having to call locate/with-theme?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of doing what you said. To achieve fast incremental compilation, Typst is essentially pure functional and no variable should be changed.